# Passing cython function to cython function

Tags: python, function-pointers, cython

I have a Cython function where I would like to pass in a serialization function as a parameter:

```
cdef my_serializer(serialization_func, data):
    return serialization_func(data)
```

All the serializers I'm going to be dealing with (msgpack, ujson) are also C/cython functions. What's the proper way to declare serialization_func so Cython can do early binding?

Comment: If `serialization_func` is a function, why are you calling a method on it to do the serialization?

Comment: You're totally right, that dumps() shouldn't have been there. Edited

Answer (score 3):

This works and is reasonably readable:

```
ctypedef void (*SERIALIZATION_FUNC)(char *data)

cdef void my_serializer(SERIALIZATION_FUNC func, char *data):
    func(data)
```

Alternately, if you really want to use python objects as parameters and return values

```
ctypedef object (*SERIALIZATION_FUNC)(object data)

cdef my_serializer(SERIALIZATION_FUNC func, data):
    return func(data)
```